# How to effectively remove white glue from a wall?

Tags: walls, paint, adhesive, removal

I have been removing some wood strips from a painted wall (see the image attached) which were attached using white glue.
[image]
After the whole process, it has naturally left a variety of rests on the wall, as you can see on this second picture:
[image]
As the ultimate goal is to paint over this green colour and get rid of it, I am not too concerned about the holes in the plaster, as I will just putty them and later use primer and the white paint on top of it. However, the white glue is becoming a nightmare: I have tried scraping or sandpapering them, and apart from being really time consuming, the results are not as smooth as desired.

Is there any method you know to effectively remove these white glue stains and leave the surface, if not as new, at least ready to be painted over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like you have three issues here.

1. In some spots you have glue that has peeled paint off the wall.
2. In other spots you have glue that has peeled off paint *and* plaster (or possibly just multiple layers of paint; hard to tell from just a photo).
3. In still other spots you still have glue.

You need to remove the remaining glue, which could be done carefully with a decent chisel or even a drywall knife.  Then you need to fill and sand all the divots (both types) left by removing the glue—joint compound is probably OK here.  Then prime and paint.  Looks like you have some significant orange peel, so you probably want to use a thick-ish primer like Zinsser 1-2-3, which will give you similar texture on the repaired areas.

Answer (score 0):

If it's truly white glue (which I doubt - more likely some sort of construction adhesive or adhesive caulk), then putting a damp cloth on it will cause it to soften up. With persistence, the white glue can slowly be wetted and removed through keeping it damp and working it off bit by bit.